# Map with Class as key

Tags: java, dictionary

can anybody explain me how to use this kind of map?

```
Map<Class, Set<Robot>>
```

where Robot is a class that defines a robot. Thank's.

Comment: Please describe better your problem, what you want and what you tried otherwise your question will be closed as it is not clear enough

Comment: How would you like to use the map; what is the context here?

Comment: You have a list of Robots which are stored by a key - which itself is dtermined by a classname.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Where did you see list here? Set  is not a list.
And, again, there is nothing about class *name*, only the class itself.

Comment: @user882813 you are right with that. My fault here.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java Map Interface you have the freedom of using Any Object as the key of the Map.Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of the Map interface for more clear understanding.
You can archive the above by simply following the below approach.

**Variables and Classes used in the exmple:**

- Robot - Your Robot Class
- KeyClass - The class you need as the key in the map.
- robots - An set of the Robot instances.

**Code**
You can initialized a Map using the following code.

```
Map<Class, Set<Robot>> robotMap  = new HashMap<Class, Set<Robot>>();
```

You can insert elements to the Map by using the following code.

```
robotMap.put(KeyClass.class, robots);
```

You can read element from the map using the following code.

```
robotMap.get(KeyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think answer is in your edited question.

```
Map<Class, Set<Robot>> mapObj  = new HashMap<Class, Set<Robot>>();
```

according below example you can program

```
Map<Class, String> mapObj  = new HashMap<Class, String>();
        mapObj.put(String.class, "");
        mapObj.get(String.class);
```

Instead of using Class as key you can use Object class like

```
Map<Object, Set<Robot>> mapObj  = new HashMap<Object, Set<Robot>>();
```

**when you iterate this map you can use instaceof to check class type**.